# How do I take inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{-2s+3}{s^2-2s+2}$?

Tags: laplace-transform, integral-transforms

How do I take inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{-2s+3}{s^2-2s+2}$?
I have checked my transform table and there is not a suitable case for this expression.

Comment: You mean the inverse Laplace's transform, don't you?

Comment: Since the denominator is an "irreducible quadratic", you will need to "complete the square" in the denominator, then make a "partial fraction decomposition" to have one term with a numerator which is a constant and another with a multiple of $ \ s \ $ (or, really, $ \ s \ $ minus a constant). The inverse transforms will be functions involving exponential functions times sine or cosine functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try this (slighlty) different approach:

Let $F(s)$ be the function to be inverse-Laplace transformed. Then, $F(s)$ admits the following partial fraction decomposition:

$$F(s) = \frac{A_1}{s-s_1} + \frac{A_2}{s-s_2},$$ where $s_1 = 1-i$, $s_2 = \overline{s}_1 = 1+i$, are the complex roots of the denominator, $A_1 = \lim_{s\to  s_1} (s-s_1) F(s) = -1+i/2$ and $A_2 = \overline{A}_1 = \lim_{s\to s_2}(s-s_2) F(s) = -1-i/2$. Now take inverse Laplace's transform on each term to get:

$$f(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}[F(s)] = A_1 e^{s_1 t} + A_2 e^{s_2 t},$$ since $A_1$ and $A_2$ are complex conjugates as well as $s_1$ and $s_2$, the result is real, which you can easily prove with the help of Euler's identity: $e^{ix} = \cos{x} + i \sin{x}$.

I hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! Very educational, but at this moment I need the "simplest" answer, involving non-complex approaches.

Comment: @Dmoreno, can you kindly provide a reference for the partial fraction decomposition and the inversion of complex linear factors? I have never seen it motivated on books.

Comment: Hi @KristiansKuhta. I'm glad you find this interesting and I'm sure you will discover how complex numbers make this so easy! On the other hand, Marco, do you mean how did I obtain the $A_i$ coefficients? This is a consequence of the application of residues. See this:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Residue_method.

Comment: no, I mean that the standard inversion theorems require that $1/(s-s_1)$ are real quantities, but you use $s_i$ as complex numbers, with those theorems you are not allowed to do that. Are you assuming a stronger theorem, e.g. the Paley-Wiener theorem?
This issue is the main reason to use the completion of the square and not to split the second degree polynomial in linear complex factors.

Answer (score 2):

To perform the inverse Laplace transform you need to complete the square at the denominator, 
$$ s^2-2s+2=(s-1)^2+1$$
so you rewrite your expression as

$$\frac{-2s+3}{(s-1)^2+1}= -2 \frac{(s-1)}{(s-1)^2+1}+\frac{(3-2)}{(s-1)^2+1}$$

now these expressions are standard on tables "exponentially decaying
 sine/cosine wave. The inverse transform is then 
$$e^t(-2\cos t+\sin t).$$

Comment: yes of course, thanks.